# Image of the reduction of a maximal order in a central simple algebra over $\mathbb Q$

Tags: nt.number-theory, linear-algebra, algebraic-groups, noncommutative-algebra

Suppose $A$ is a $n^2$-dimensional central simple algebra over $\mathbb Q$, and $O_A$ is an maximal order of $A$.

Choose a finite place $p$ such that $A \otimes \mathbb Q_p \cong M_n(\mathbb Q_p)$. Then we have the reduction map $\text{red}: O_A^{\times} \to O_{A \otimes \mathbb Z_p}^{\times} \cong  GL_n(\mathbb Z_p) \to GL_n(\mathbb F_p)$.

Can we describe the image of $\text{red}$ (up to conjugacy) using the Brauer invariants of $A$? Is its always not contain in a Borel subgroup of $GL_n(\mathbb F_p)$ (at least for large $p$)?

The case $A$ is split is standard.